# how to close Network reply alert Dialog from background service in android?

Tags: android

Hi All i am working an callforwarding app.

so here my requirement is that i will give the user to set one number to callforwarding at particular time with 10 minutes intervals . After set number he will close his APP. But after 10 minutes call should forward to particular number.

So for that purpose i use background service.

My code is for forwarding is

```
private synchronized void callFunction(String phonenumber)
    {

        Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); // ACTION_CALL
        intentCallForward.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Uri uri2=null;
        try{
            uri2 = Uri.fromParts("tel", phonenumber, "#");
            intentCallForward.setData(uri2);
            startActivityForResult(intentCallForward, 6666);
            //startActivity(intentCallForward);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }finally
        {
            if(uri2!=null)
            {
                uri2=null;
            }
            intentCallForward=null;
        }
    }
```

Tthis code is working fine when time reach it automatically set forwarding

My problem is that after i request forwarding, network provider will give me reply with meaning full message **Alert Dialog** like following image

But my service is calling in 1 hour 12 times. and i got 12 Alerts. That alerts block user home screen after click **OK** then only it will open home screen

If one message ok but if make a call 50 times i got 50 messages. It is hard to click on OK button in 50 times.

So is it posible to close that **Network replay alert Dialog** Pragmatically from Background service?

Thank in advance

[image]

Comment: which class show this dialog service or some other clas

Comment: fro service i call that function so it display on home screen

Comment: You ca try this : send a broadcast when you receive reply from network provider receive this broadcast in service and dismiss dialog. I am not sure about efficiency, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not close that popup programatically, because it is comming from the network and it should prompt to user: `your request is success or not?`. So it is required to be done on the phone side.